# How to remove static without getting a StackOverflowError?

Tags: java

I've been tasked to pass all the assertion checks in the Exercise class only editing between the areas marked with commenting. Everything between there is what I've attempted so far and it seems to work. However, it's been noted that I'm not allowed to use the "static" keyword, and if I try removing my uses of it I get a StackOverflowError. I was wondering if there is a way I can remove them while avoiding the error and passing all the assertion checks. To be clear the static keywords outside of the area marked are allowed, the "succ()" method gets the successor and the "pred()" method gets the predecessor.

```java
class Num {
    static Num zero() {
        return instance;
    }
    static Num instance = new Num();
/// START HERE
    private static final Num zero = zero();
    private static final Num one = new Num();
    private static final Num two = new Num();

    public Num succ() {
        if(this == zero) return one;
        if(this == one) return two;
        return null;
    }

    public Num pred() {
        if(this == two) return one;
        if(this == one) return zero;
        return null;
    }
// END HERE
}
public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String[]arg){
    Num zero=Num.zero();
    assert zero==Num.zero();
    Num one=zero.succ();
    assert one!=zero;
    Num two=one.succ();
    assert one!=two;
    assert two.pred()==one;
    Num two2=one.succ();
    Num tree=two.succ();
    assert two==two2;
    assert tree==two.succ();
    assert tree.pred().pred()==one;
    assert two.pred()==zero.succ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting a `StackOverflowError`? Can you show us your modified code, without the `static` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at comments by @Taschi and @user, here is a new version that lazily builds a doubly-linked list, implementing Peano numbers. I should have thought about this earlier:

```
/// START HERE
private Num prev = null;
private Num next = null;

public Num succ() {
    // lazily initialize next only if not already set
    if (next == null) {
        next = new Num();
        next.prev = this;
    }
    return next;
}

public Num pred() {
    return prev;
}
// END HERE
```

**Old answer**

The definition of `Num` appears to be that of a singleton: a single instance is created, and returned via `zero`. However, for this to work, singletons cannot be used:

`assert one != zero`

Therefore, methods `succ()` and `pred()` are expected to build new objects; but always the exact same objects, because otherwise `two == two2` would be false.

Regardless of the (very questionable for anything but puzzle-solving) educational properties of the exercise, I propose the following code, which avoids use of the static keyword in the highlighted area:

```
/// START HERE
enum N { 
    ZERO(zero()), ONE(new Num()), TWO(new Num()), THREE(new Num());
    private Num v;
    N(Num v) { this.v = v;}
}; // look ma, no statics!
private N n=N.ZERO; 

public Num succ() {
    switch(n) {
        case ZERO: return N.ONE.v;
        case ONE: return N.TWO.v;
        case TWO: return N.THREE.v;
        default: return null;
    }
}

public Num pred() {
    switch(n) {
        case ONE: return N.ZERO.v;
        case TWO: return N.ONE.v;
        case THREE: return N.TWO.v;
        default: return null;
    }
}
// END HERE
```

Comment: Nice way to implement it without getting a stack overflow and without keeping an integer field

Answer (score 5):

You cannot.

If you do, every time you create a new `Num` object, it will create three new `Num` objects (zero, one and two), and each one of those will also create three new `Num` objects, repeat ad nauseam.

Obviously, you'll run out of space on the stack sooner or later.

Your entire approach to this exercise is very questionable, to be honest. I doubt hardcoding simple maths is what your teacher wants you to do, even if it does technically pass the assertions.

Comment: That's fair and I figured that was the issue. If you have time could you explain how I'd be expected to use math for this problem rather than hardcoding as there's no Integers or Enums or anything I could possibly use to calculate this with? It's the reason I resorted to this method in the first place.

Comment: Declare your own member variable and do maths on that.

Comment: I think it's the exercises fault, and not OP's - but there are ways to torture Java into doing what is expected

Comment: It's unclear whether the exercise wants Peano numbers, in which case you'd have to create a constructor that takes in another `Num` object (`null` in the case of `zero`)

Comment: @user I tried to go that route, but you need a repeatable way of building the exact same instance over and over agan: `zero().succ() == zero().succ()` is hard without `static`, while `zero().succ().equals(zero().succ())` would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Taschi member variables do not come into play when `==` is used to compare instances. In C++, the exercise would be easy: `==` can be overloaded there.

Comment: @tucuxi, you're right. I didn't notice that particular bit of silliness in the exercise. Then again, you could have `next` as a member variable which is initially `null` and gets initialized to `new Num() ` when succ() is called on a particular Num instance for the firts time.

Comment: @Taschi I would rather have a member variable `pred` that is set to `null` for `zero` and whatever is before that for all other numbers.

Comment: @user - Peano numbers via [lazy doubly-linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62541219/15472).